# how to identify the ip address of mininet network?

Tags: sdn, mininet, ryu

I have set up a preview of ryu controller and mininet,but i am not able to identify the mininet ip address as well as not able to ping from other vm machine.But i am able to get the ip of mininet sub-host.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from Hasan Aga under?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ping a VM from another VM, you must configure 'Bridged Adapter` for each VM, that way they both have access to the network that you are using, take a look at [this](https://linuxhint.com/use-virtualbox-bridged-adapter/).